# How get macro data from Excel / C#?

Tags: c#, .net, excel

Can I get contains macros in my excel file with a ClosedXML or Module name may be? And if not, how we can get it from stream file with another tools?

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand your question. Do you want a list of the macros contained in an Excel macro enabled workbook (.xlsm) using C#?

Comment: @Nicholas Yes!!! Use ClosedXML

Comment: It doesn't look like ClosedXML offers that functionality. Have you looked at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel?

Comment: Yes. but is not support Stream i think> only path to file.

Comment: Maybe this would be helpful. [Read Excel VBA macros and functions through C#](https://brandewinder.com/2009/12/12/Read-Excel-VBA-macros-and-functions-through-C/)

Comment: No parametrs Open(string fileName) . I need Open(Stream fileName)